# Firebase Realtime Database Data Automatically Gets Deleted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Image of the problem I am referring To:
[image]
 I am trying to create an Educational app where users can create classrooms and can give work like assignments, homework and video lectures to their students. I am using Firebase Realtime Database as a BAAS. Everything was working fine until now, When I create a classroom i.e. set a value at a Node under "Classrooms" node, the data from the whole database gets deleted and then a new node under main database called "Classrooms" gets created and then the value of a Classroom object is set there. I am troubleshooting this since 3 days now, have saw simillar questions on stack overflow, but the most of the questions were not having answers, and I tried the answers of those questions having answers, but they didn't work. Please help me, I am stuck due to this problem and am unable to release my app for public usage.

To help with debugging, here is some code that I am using:

```
createClassroom.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String proposedName = className.getText().toString();
        if (proposedName.equals("")) {
                //some checks for ensuring proposed name is a valid classroom name
        } else {

            // Some code which sets the values of Classroom Object (setters)

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .child("Classrooms")
                    .child(classroom.getId())
                    .setValue(classroom.toMap())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                        updateUserInDb())
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, "Failed Due To " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
        }
    });
}
```

I have also tried this using FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classrooms")... method, but it doesn't change anything.

Also, here is the updateUserInDb() method:

```
 private void updateUserInDb() {
    String user_id = DataFlowGlobals.user.getId();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Users")
            .child(user_id)
            .child("cre")
            .child(classroom.getId())
            .setValue(classroom.getId())
            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Toast.makeText(context, "Classroom Created Successfully........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, "Failed due to " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

    finish();
  }
```

Please help as soon as possible, thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT 1: I have added the image of the issue, which I am experiencing.**

Comment: I think all child node doesn't exists. Can you make sure that all of your `child` exists in firebase?

Comment: do you mean all the child nodes of a particular Classroom or the "Classrooms" node ? The node "Classrooms" doesn't exist at first, but it gets created after all of the data is deleted automatically. I am editing my question with a screenshot displaying what i is my problem.

Comment: Don't know what's the problem. But you can try Database `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Classrooms").child(classroom.getId());` Then setValue on `ref`. Use this also for `updateUserinDb`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but It didn't work. The data still gets deleted. I don't know why is it happening. I had the same code previously, but now only it does this problem.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Don't know the problem. By the way let us know if you find any solution.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply, I was unable to find Any Solution To the problem. Hence I am now migrating my code for using Cloud Firestore. Didn't want to waste time. I recommend anyone having this problem to migrate to cloud firestore as I WAS NOT ABLE TO FIND A SOLUTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to get the reference of the database first then you can able perform any option on the child node. like blow

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Classrooms")
                .child(classroom.getId())
                .setValue(classroom.toMap())
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    updateUserInDb())
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, "Failed Due To " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Happy coding...

Comment: I have already had this code before, but this didn't work. Please provide an alternative solution. Thank you for the suggestion !

Comment: @user13884915 If it didn't work, then why you tick this as accepted answer??